# Select checkbox text not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Below is my code. The text is not changing when I select the checkbox.
The text for the checkbox should change but it is not.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OX</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function () {
        window.alert(5 + 6);
    if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
          window.alert(5 + 6);
        $("#description").html("Your Checked 1");

    } else {
        $("#description").html("No check");
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" value="0" id="checkbox1" name=""/> Answer one <br/></input>
<span id="description"> Hi Your Text will come here </span>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're running the code before the elements exist. Look at $(document).ready so that the code doesn't fire until the dom is ready https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Or ..  Move your JS code BELOW the HTML

Comment: Also, [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is an ["empty element"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element), meaning that it cannot contain any child nodes. I suggest using a [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element rather than an invalid closing `</input>` tag. See the ["Simple label example" at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Simple_label_example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use try to load `Jquery` and most of other `JS frameworks` before the end of body tags and use to bind all `Jquery` code in `$(document).ready` function

Edited code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OX</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" value="0" id="checkbox1" name=""/> 
<label for="">Answer one</label> <br/>

<span id="description"> Hi Your Text will come here </span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').on('change', function () {
        window.alert(5 + 6);
        if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
              window.alert(5 + 6);
            $("#description").html("Your Checked 1");

        } else {
            $("#description").html("No check");
        }
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your script is trying to operate before the DOM is loaded. How can you catch a checkbox that isn't even loaded on the page yet. The simple solution is to use document.ready handler such as [`$( document ).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) which will allow you to do just that.

I have a working example with the addition of this code as well below. Run it and have a look.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>OX</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
        window.alert(5 + 6);
        if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
          window.alert(5 + 6);
          $("#description").html("Your Checked 1");

        } else {
          $("#description").html("No check");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="checkbox1" name="" />Answer one
  <br/>
  </input>
  <span id="description"> Hi Your Text will come here </span> 
</body>

</html>
```